# Gcd and coprime numbers

Tags: number-theory

Assume: $c$ divides $ab$ and $GCD(a,c)=1$. Calculate $GCD(b,c)$.I think that $GCD(b,c)=c$ But how to prove it. Help me, please.

Answer (score 1):

To prove that $GCD(b, c) = c$, all you need to do is prove that $c$ divides $b$.

Answer (score 1):

From Euclid's algorithm, we can find integers $\lambda, \mu$ such that $$\lambda a+\mu c=1$$

It follows that $$\lambda ab+\mu cb=b$$

And since $c$ divides both terms on the left, we must have $c|b$.  That's all you need.

Answer (score 0):

$c|b$(cannot divide $a$)  so $LCM(b,c)=b$

$GCD(b,c)={{bc}\over {LCM(b,c)}}=c$